# Retornando valores do callback na função principal - JS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho uma função principal e uma função de callback dentro dela. Necessito que, dependendo do retorno do callback a minha função principal retorne algo, observe:

```
function funcaoPrincipal(){
    funcaoCallback(function(erro){
        if(erro){
            //retorna false para a função principal
        }else{
            //retorna true para a função principal
        }
    });
}
```

como posso realizar isso? já tentei declarar uma variável no escopo da função principal e modifica-la dentro do callback porém, sem sucesso.

Comment: Você está precisando pegar o retorno da `funcaoPrincipal` onde ela é chamada? Algo do tipo: `const retorno = funcaoPrincipal()`? Não sei se entendi muito bem o quer.

Comment: Eu apenas preciso retornar algo pra função principal dependendo da situação do callback, se eu utilizar um return dentro do callback ele não irá retornar na função principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é usar uma variável na `funcaoPrincipal` e alterar o valor dela dentro de `callback`:

```
function funcaoPrincipal(){
    let deuErro;
    funcaoCallback(function(erro) {
        if(erro) {
            deuErro = true;
        } else {
            deuErro = false;
        }
    });
    console.log(deuErro) // true;
}
```

Porém, se o callback é executado de forma assíncrona, ela ainda não estará disponível logo abaixo da sua chamada:

```
function funcaoPrincipal(){
    let deuErro;
    funcaoCallback(function(erro) {
        if(erro) {
            deuErro = true;
        } else {
            deuErro = false;
        }
    });
    // quando chegar aqui, não vai ter passado pelo callback
    console.log(deuErro); // undefined
}
```

Uma solução seria fazer o que está fazendo na `funcaoPrincipal` no callback:

```
function funcaoPrincipal(){
    let deuErro;
    funcaoCallback(function(erro) {
        if(erro) {
            deuErro = true;
        } else {
            deuErro = false;
        }

        // trabalhar com a variável aqui
        console.log(deuErro); // true
    });
}
```

Mas uma forma ainda mais interessante seria utilizar uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Com isso, conseguiria fazer algo como:

```
function funcaoPrincipal() {

    funcaoCallback()
        .then(function() {
            // sucesso
        })
        .catch(function () {
            // erro
        });
}

function funcaoCallback() {
    return Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (...) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            reject();
        }
    });
}
```